# Finding nearest point A to Point B and then excluding all point Bs without nearest point A?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, proximity

I'm using GIS for the first time for a university project, ArcGIS specifically. As far as I'm aware I have access to the full suite of Arc software but I'm typing this out from home so can't check right now.

I've got two datasets; one is all of the kingfisher sightings uploaded to a biodiversity database in 2015 (~18000 data points) and the other is a list of all the water bodies in England surveyed by the Environment Agency in 2015 and a rating for each (poor, moderate, excellent) based on various factors (~800 data points).

Firstly, I'm not bothered about how far the kingfisher sightings are from the water bodies in terms of m or km etc. What I want to do is find the nearest water body to each kingfisher sighting and then separate out all of the water bodies that aren't the nearest water body for any kingfishers. Basically I want to know which of the water bodies on my list aren't used by kingfishers.

I've looked at some other forum posts and from what I've seen I think what I want to do is possible, but I haven't seen any that want to extract data about the points that aren't linked.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Near tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/near.htm) with Kingfisher sightings as in_features and water bodies as near features. Fields will be added to Kingfisher attribute table holding object ID of the nearest water and distance.
2. [Join this attribute table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/essentials-of-joining-tables.htm) to water bodies with option Keep only matching records with objectid as common field. You will now only have the water bodies which are the closest ones to Kingfisher sightings.
3. Use Copy Features to save the joined tables as a new feature class